# Any way to measure distance between current and all other lines in Eclipse editors?

Tags: eclipse, vim, eclim

I'm using the Vim plugin in Eclipse, and only thing that would make me more happy would be if I could somehow measure distance from current line to all other lines. It is kinda hard to guess exact number of lines i.e. is that 8 or 9 lines I need to move down? So some kind of modification of the line numbering bar that changes the numbers to be relative (+-) to the current line would be nice to have.

Is there something like this? If not I'm so desperate that I will probably try to build it myself.

Comment: Can't you just subtract the line you want to go to from the line that's currently highlighted?

Comment: Yeah, it is possible, but not convenient, I've enjoyed substracting 2 small numbers as a kid long enough, so I would be happier if my computer could handle it now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standalone vim has the `relativenumber` option in version 7.3 that does what you want.  I don't know how closely related that is to the eclipse plugin, or how difficult it would be to port over.

Before that option was available, I used to make heavy use of marks instead of guessing relative line numbers.  Basically, you mark a line with `m` followed by a letter of the alphabet, and can move to that line with `'` followed by the same letter.  Maybe that will help if you don't already know about it.

Answer (score 3):

Install the [Relative Line Number Ruler plugin](http://matf.github.com/relativenumberruler). It shows a relative line number ruler by default, which can be disabled using the context menu on the ruler. The diff/absolute line number ruler can still be displayed if desired.

This is useful if you're using a Vi emulation plugin such as [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

The relative number plugin can be so slow. I am using this in my vimrc:

```
let g:RTL = 1

function X_rtl()
    if g:RTL == 0
        set number 
        let g:RTL = 1
    else
        set relativenumber
        let g:RTL = 0
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <esc><esc> :call X_rtl()<cr>
```

So if I hit escape twice, it will change numbers to relative, and if I hit it twice again, it will switch back;